# If $g\circ f=f$ in a category, then is $g$ necessarily the identity morphism?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

I know momomorphisms are left-cancellative and epimorphisms are right-cancellative. But, let $C$ be any object in an arbitrary category $\mathbf{C}$, and $f,g:C\to C$ be any morphisms st $gf=f$. Then, do we necessarily have $g=\text{id}$? I am asking for some kind of cancellative law wrt composition. If it is not true, is there a handy counter-example? Also are there some special type of categories where this statement is indeed true?

If $\mathbf C$ were an abelian category, then we have $0=gf-f=(g-\text{id})f$. Now the question reduces to can two non-zero morphisms compose to give a zero morphism (ie morphisms in $\mathbf C$ that factorize through a zero object, or equivalently constant and co-constant, see definitions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_morphism))?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not even true in $\mathsf{Set}$: take $C=\{1,2\}$, $f=g$ mapping everything to $1$.

Now for an abelian category take $\mathsf{AbGroup}$, $C=C_2\times C_2$, $f=g$ sending $(x,y)$ to $(x,0)$.

You can see two nonzero endo-maps composing to zero in any abelian category by taking any nonzero object $D$, letting $C=D\oplus D$, and letting $f=\mathrm{id}\oplus \mathbf{z}$ and $g=\mathbf{z}\oplus \mathrm{id}$, where $\mathbf{z}$ is the zero map from $D$ to itself.

For that matter, the zero map composed with itself equals the zero map, and any non-identity projection in vector spaces or modules composed with itself equals itself.

Answer (score 5):

A particularly simple class of counterexamples is given by taking $f = g$. Then you are asking for a morphism $f$ such that $f \circ f = f$ but $f \neq 1$, i.e. any nontrivial idempotent. It is very easy to find examples in most categories of interest.

However, this condition will hold in any category for which every morphism is an epimorphism. These are known as [right-cancellative](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cancellative+category) categories. These do arise in some situations, for instance [in categorical model theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.11307).